# undefined method `initialize_attributes' for #<Class> when object.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I update rails from 4.0.0 to 4.2.x（I tried 4.2.1 and 4.2.7），each model's new method raise a Expection：

```
[10] pry(main)> User
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean, name: string, sex: integer, phone: string, created_by_id: integer, current_project: integer, avatar_file_name: string, avatar_content_type: string, avatar_file_size: integer, avatar_updated_at: datetime)

[11] pry(main)>u = User.new
NoMethodError (undefined method `initialize_attributes' for #<Class:0x007f9bcda69710>
```

But everything work fine when I use rails 4.0.0

Can someone help me， thx

Comment: full stacktrace：[12] pry(main)> u = User.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `initialize_attributes' for #<Class:0x007ffab438cd70>
Did you mean?  initialize_dup
from /Users/kalvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'

Comment: solved! this methond has remove in 4.2.0~https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/032a8d9dc95f40581d8cbda2c297b50edaa44e6f~ I have specic 'protected_attributes' version to '1.0.3' in my gem file，when I remove version and bundle update, every thing goes fine